# Resize and reposition a disk so its bounding box accommodates other objects

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles, coordinate-systems

#### This is a continuation of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4152307/932205).

I have a circle or disk with some rectangles located on its circumference
which have arbitrary widths, heights, and angles (by angle I mean the line connecting center of the circle to center of the rectangle). An example angle is shown for one of the rectangles with pink lines.

The center coordinate of the circle is (*centerX*, *centerY*) and its radius is *r*.
The widths and heights of the rectangles and angles of the lines connecting circle center to each rectangle center are available too.

How can I find a new radius *r* and a new *centerX* and *CenterY* for the disk so that it has maximum area and the previous bounding box of the disk (dashed green line) can fully accommodate all the rectangles?

[image: An example image showing the problem]

## A relaxed version of the problem

If the above problem is too hard to solve, then, how can I just modify the circle radius *r* (its center stays the same) so that its previous bounding box can contain all the rectangles?

[image: An example image showing the simplified problem]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to do.  From your diagrams it would appear that you want to scale down and translate the figure comprising the circle and rectangles so that it remains similar to the original figure (i.e. its *relative* dimensions remain the same) and it lies inside the original bounding box, and is as large as possible (i.e. scaled down as little as possible).  Is that correct?

Comment: @lonzaleggiera I want to scale down **only the circle** so that it has maximum area and all the other rectangles will be contained in the green bounding box. The pink lines show an example angle of a rectangle (*rectangle2*).

Comment: @Mahozad The rectangles obviously can't remain in their initial positions — how would you expect them to be positioned with respect to the new circle, _precisely_? I think that is more non-trivial to formalize than you might think.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki This post, more or less, continues [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4152307/932205).

Comment: @Mahozad If you only scale down the circle, I can see two issues that may prevent you achieving your goal:
$$\ $$ 1. If either the height or the width of any of the rectangles is greater than the diameter of the circle, then it can never fit inside the bounding box, no matter what translation you apply to it;

Comment: 2. If the rectangles are required to continue touching the circle, and their centres are required to subtend the same angle to the horizontal at the circle's centre, then some of the rectangles may have to overlap when the circle is made sufficiently small.  Is this allowed?  If not, what do you want to happen to them instead?

Comment: @lonzaleggiera Let's assume that all the rectangles are small enough (their width and height is much smaller than the circle radius) and that they can overlap.

Comment: I suspect even the relaxed version has only numerical solutions, given how nonlinearily the size of the enclosing axis aligned bounding box depends on the disk radius (I wager lots of local maxima very near to global maxima).  Personally, I'd use a fixed-size radius change followed by a binary search on the largest radius change that causes the aabb to become large enough, so that even though there are no guarantees the optimum (maximum) disk radius is reached, the solution is close enough.  This should also work for the case where the disk is first translated and then shrunk. [...]

Comment: [...] The "trick" is to keep the initial/current configuration, and to just vary the target configuration, and apply the same shrinking logic, then find out the resulting aabb size, I believe.  So, in a sense, this is much more a "programming" or "algorithmic" question than a geometric one.  I could post a detailed description and say Python code as an "answer"; would it be acceptable here, considering this is math SE?

Comment: In fact, all this is used to develop an Android library. So I would appreciate code as well.

Comment: From your sketches, we gather that we need to deal with two different kinds of rectangles. My question is about the type of rectangles (e.g. yellow rectangle), which have tangents of the circle as one of their sides. Unless the point shared by the circle and the side of this type of rectangle is the midpoint of that side, there is no way we can preserve the slope (i.e. angle) of the line joining the centers of the circle and the rectangle when we do this tucking-in of rectangles. Therefore, can we assume that the sides of such rectangles always touch the circle at their mid points?

Answer (score 0):

If an axis-aligned box is centered at $(x, y)$, its width being $2 w$, height $2 h$, the distance from the box to origin is $d$,
$$d = \begin{cases}
\sqrt{c_x^2 + c_y^2}, & \text{if } c_x \gt 0 \text{ and } c_y \gt 0 \\
\max(0,\, c_x,\, c_y), & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{cases} \tag{1a}\label{G1a}$$
where
$$c_x = \lvert x \rvert - w , \quad c_y = \lvert y \rvert - h \tag{1b}\label{G1b}$$
are the distance between the box and the $y$ axis, and the distance between the box and the $x$ axis, respectively.

If we use
$$r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}, \quad
a_x = \frac{\lvert x \rvert}{r}, \quad
a_y = \frac{\lvert y \rvert}{r} \tag{1c}\label{G1c}$$
then we can solve $\eqref{G1a}$ for $r$ via
$$\begin{aligned}
b &= w a_x + h a_y \\
c &= h a_x - w a_y \\
r_{xy} &= b + \sqrt{d^2 - c^2} \\
r_{x} &= \frac{d + w}{a_x} \\
r_{y} &= \frac{d + h}{a_y} \\
r &= \begin{cases}
r_{xy}, & d^2 \ge c^2 \text{ and } r_{xy} a_x \ge w \text{ and } r_{xy} a_y \ge h \\
r_{x},  & d^2 \ge c^2 \text{ and } r_{xy} a_x \ge w \text{ and } r_{xy} a_y \lt h \\
r_{y},  & d^2 \ge c^2 \text{ and } r_{xy} a_x \lt w \text{ and } r_{xy} a_y \ge h \\
0,      & d^2 \ge c^2 \text{ and } r_{xy} a_x \lt w \text{ and } r_{xy} a_y \lt h \\
r_{x},  & d^2 \lt c^2 \text{ and } c \gt 0 \\
r_{y},  & d^2 \lt c^2 \text{ and } c \lt 0 \\
\end{cases} \\
\end{aligned} \tag{1d}\label{G1d}$$

Here is an example Python 3 implementation, `rect.py`. You can import the Rect type to use in your own code via `from rect import Rect`, run `pydoc3 rect` to see the documentation of the Rect class it implements, or run the file using e.g. `python3 -B rect.py` to test it with randomly generated rectangles.  It is licensed under the [Creative Commons Zero v1.0 Universal](https://spdx.org/licenses/CC0-1.0.html) license; so feel free to reuse as you wish.

```
# SPDX-License-Identifier: CC0-1.0

from math import pi, atan2, tan, sqrt, sin, cos, pi

class Rect:
    __slots__ = ( "_w", "_h", "_a", "_d", "_x", "_y" )

    def __init__(self, width=0.0, height=0.0, distance=0.0, angle=0.0):
        w = 0.5 * abs(float(width))
        h = 0.5 * abs(float(height))
        a = float(angle) * pi / 180.0
        d = abs(float(distance))

        self._w = w         # Half-width
        self._h = h         # Half-height
        self._a = a         # Angle in radians
        self._d = d         # Distance from perimeter to origin
        self._set_x_y_d(d)

    def _set_x_y_d(self, distance):
        """Internal: Recalculates self._x and self._y based on perimeter to origin distance"""
        d = abs(float(distance))
        w = self._w
        h = self._h

        dx = cos(self._a)
        dy = sin(self._a)
        ax = abs(dx)
        ay = abs(dy)

        b = w*ax + h*ay
        c = h*ax - w*ay

        dd = d*d
        cc = c*c

        if dd >= cc:
            r = b + sqrt(dd - cc)
            cx = r*ax - w
            cy = r*ay - h
            if cx > 0 and cy > 0:
                # r is correct
                pass
            elif cx > 0:
                r = (d + w) / ax
            elif cy > 0:
                r = (d + h) / ay
            else:
                r = d + sqrt(w*w + h*h)
        elif c > 0:
            r = (d + w) / ax
        else:
            r = (d + h) / ay

        self._d = d
        self._x = r*dx
        self._y = r*dy

    def _set_x_y_r(self, distance):
        """Internal: Recalculates self._x and self._y and self._d based on center to center distance"""
        r  = abs(float(distance))
        dx = cos(self._a)
        dy = sin(self._a)
        cx = r * abs(dx) - self._w
        cy = r * abs(dy) - self._h
        if cx >= 0 and cy >= 0:
            d = sqrt(cx*cx + cy*cy)
        elif cx > 0:
            d = cx
        elif cy > 0:
            d = cy
        else:
            r = 0
            d = 0

        self._d = d
        self._x = r*dx
        self._y = r*dy

    @property
    def copy(self):
        """Yields an exact duplicate of this rectangle object"""
        r = Rect()
        r._w = self._w
        r._h = self._h
        r._a = self._a
        r._d = self._d
        r._x = self._x
        r._y = self._y
        return r

    @property
    def width(self):
        """Rectangle size along X axis (width)"""
        return 2 * self._w

    @width.setter
    def width(self, width):
        self._w = 0.5 * abs(float(width))
        self._set_x_y_d(self._d)

    @property
    def height(self):
        """Rectangle size along Y axis (height)"""
        return 2 * self._h

    @height.setter
    def height(self, height):
        self._h = 0.5 * abs(float(height))
        self._set_x_y_d(self._d)

    @property
    def distance(self):
        """Rectangle distance from center of disk"""
        return self._d

    @distance.setter
    def distance(self, distance):
        self._set_x_y_d(float(distance))

    @property
    def radius(self):
        """Distance from center of rectangle to center of disk"""
        return sqrt(self._x*self._x + self._y*self._y)

    @radius.setter
    def radius(self, radius):
        self._set_x_y_r(float(radius))

    @property
    def angle(self):
        """Rectangle direction, angle in degrees"""
        return self._a * 180.0 / pi

    @angle.setter
    def angle(self, angle):
        self._a = float(angle) * pi / 180.0
        self._set_x_y_d(self._d)

    @property
    def center(self):
        """Rectangle center as a tuple"""
        return (self._x, self._y)

    @center.setter
    def center(self, p):
        x = float(p[0])
        y = float(p[1])
        self._a = atan2(y, x)
        self._set_x_y_r(sqrt(x*x + y*y))

    @property
    def min(self):
        """Rectangle corner with the smallest coordinates as a tuple"""
        return (self._x-self._w, self._y-self._h)

    @property
    def max(self):
        """Rectangle corner with the largest coordinates as a tuple"""
        return (self._x+self._w, self._y+self._h)

    @property
    def aabb(self):
        """Axis-aligned bounding box (with respect to its disk)"""
        return (self._x-self._w, self._y-self._h, self._x+self._w, self._y+self._h)

    @property
    def x(self):
        """Center X coordinate (with respect to its disk)"""
        return self._x

    @property
    def y(self):
        """Center Y coordinate (with respect to its disk)"""
        return self._y

    @property
    def xmin(self):
        """Minimum X coordinate (left edge)"""
        return self._x - self._w

    @property
    def ymin(self):
        """Minimum Y coordinate (top edge)"""
        return self._y - self._h

    @property
    def xmax(self):
        """Maximum X coordinate (right edge)"""
        return self._x + self._w

    @property
    def ymax(self):
        """Maximum Y coordinate (bottom edge)"""
        return self._y + self._h


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from random import Random

    u = Random().uniform

    rerrmax = 0.0
    derrmax = 0.0

    print("Testing Rect() radius/distance correctness.  Press Ctrl+C to stop.")

    n = 0
    while True:
        try:
            w = u(0.1, 1.0)
            h = u(0.1, 1.0)
            d = u(0.0, 1.0)
            a = u(0.0, 360.0)

            rect = Rect(w, h, d, a)
            r = rect.radius
            rect.radius = r
            R = rect.radius
            D = rect.distance

            rerr = abs(R - r)
            derr = abs(D - d)
            if rerr > rerrmax or derr > derrmax:
                rerrmax = max(rerrmax, rerr)
                derrmax = max(derrmax, derr)
                print("%-15s %-15s %-15s %-15s %-15s %-15s %-15s %-15s %-15s" % ("w = %.7f" % w, "h = %.7f" % h, "a = %6.2f" % a, "d = %.7f" % d, "D = %.7f" % D, "D-d = %+.7g" % (D-d), "r = %.7f" % r, "R = %.7f" % R, "R-r = %+.7g" % (R-r)))

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("After %d tests, maximum r error is %.16f and maximum d error is %.16f" % (n, rerrmax, derrmax))
            break

        n += 1
        if (n & 65535) == 0:
            print("After %d tests, maximum r error is %.16f and maximum d error is %.16f" % (n, rerrmax, derrmax))
```

Another file, `disk.py`, implements the disk (with associated rectangles) logic:

```
# SPDX-License-Identifier: CC0-1.0

from rect import Rect

class Disk:
    slots = ('_x', '_y', '_d', '_r')

    def __init__(self, *rects, x=0.0, y=0.0, radius=0.0):
        self._x = float(x)
        self._y = float(y)
        self._d = abs(float(radius))
        self._r = []

        if len(rects) > 0:
            for r in rects:
                if isinstance(r, Rect):
                    # Choose minimum distance among rectangles
                    if self._d == 0 or self._d > r.distance:
                        self._d = r.distance
                    self._r.append(r)
                else:
                    raise TypeError("Expected a Rect, got a %s." % str(type(r)))

    @property
    def x(self):
        """Center of the disk, X coordinate"""
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, x):
        self._x = float(x)

    @property
    def y(self):
        """Center of the disk, Y coordinate"""
        return self._y

    @y.setter
    def y(self, y):
        self._y = float(y)

    @property
    def center(self):
        """Center of the disk"""
        return (self._x, self._y)

    @center.setter
    def center(self, c):
        self._x = float(c[0])
        self._y = float(c[1])

    @property
    def aabb(self):
        """Axis-aligned bounding box"""
        abb = (-self._d, -self._d, self._d, self._d)
        for r in self._r:
            rbb = r.aabb
            abb = (min(abb[0], rbb[0]), min(abb[1], rbb[1]), max(abb[2], rbb[2]), max(abb[3], rbb[3]))
        return (abb[0]+self._x, abb[1]+self._y, abb[2]+self._x, abb[3]+self._y)

    @property
    def size(self):
        """Width and height of the axis-aligned bounding box"""
        bb = self.aabb
        return (bb[2]-bb[0], bb[3]-bb[1])

    @property
    def width(self):
        """Width of the axis-aligned bounding box"""
        bb = self.aabb
        return bb[2] - bb[0]

    @property
    def height(self):
        """Height of the axis-aligned bounding box"""
        bb = self.aabb
        return bb[3] - bb[1]

    @property
    def copy(self):
        """Independent copy of the disk and related rectangles"""
        disk = Disk()
        disk._x = self._x
        disk._y = self._y
        disk._d = self._d
        disk._r = [ r.copy for r in self._r ]
        return disk

    def size_at_radius(self, radius):
        """Axis-aligned bounding box size, if all rectangles moved to a specific distance"""
        d = abs(float(radius))
        dbb = (-d, -d, d, d)
        for r in self._r:
            c = r.copy
            c.distance = d
            rbb = c.aabb
            dbb = (min(dbb[0], rbb[0]), min(dbb[1], rbb[1]), max(dbb[2], rbb[2]), max(dbb[3], rbb[3]))
        return (dbb[2]-dbb[0], dbb[3]-dbb[1])

    def copy_at(self, radius, x=None, y=None):
        """Independent copy of the disk and rectangles, with rectangles moved to a specific distance"""
        disk = Disk()
        d = abs(float(radius))
        disk._d = d
        if x is None:
            disk._x = self._x
        else:
            disk._x = float(x)
        if y is None:
            disk._y = self._y
        else:
            disk._y = float(y)

        for r in self._r:
            c = r.copy
            c.distance = d
            disk._r.append(c)

        return disk

    @property
    def radius(self):
        """Disk radius"""
        return self._d

    @radius.setter
    def radius(self, radius=-1.0):
        if radius >= 0.0:
            d = float(radius)
        else:
            d = self._d
        for r in self._r:
            r.distance = d

    @property
    def rects(self):
        """Immutable list (tuple) of rectangles"""
        return tuple(self._r)

    def resized_to(self, width, height):
        size = ( abs(float(width)), abs(float(height)) )

        if len(self._r) < 1:
            disk = Disk()
            disk._x = self._x
            disk._y = self._y
            disk._d = 0.5*min(w, h)
            return disk
        else:
            d = self._r[0].distance
            dmin = d
            dmax = d
            for r in self._r:
                d = r.distance
                dmin = min(dmin, d)
                dmax = max(dmax, d)

        if dmin < 0:
            dmin = 0
        if dmax <= dmin:
            dmax = dmin + 1.0

        minsize = self.size_at_radius(dmin)
        maxsize = self.size_at_radius(dmax)

        while (dmin > 0) and (minsize[0] > size[0] or minsize[1] > size[1]):
            dmin = 0.5 * dmin
            minsize = self.size_at_radius(dmin)

        if (minsize[0] > size[0] or minsize[1] > size[1]):
            return self.copy_at(radius=0)

        while maxsize[0] < size[0] or maxsize[1] < size[1]:
            dmax = 2.0 * dmax
            maxsize = self.size_at_radius(dmax)

        while True:
            d = 0.5 * dmin + 0.5 * dmax
            if d == dmin or d == dmax:
                break

            dsize = self.size_at_radius(d)
            if dsize[0] > size[0] or dsize[1] > size[1]:
                dmax = d
            elif dsize[0] < size[0] or dsize[1] < size[1]:
                dmin = d
            else: break

        return self.copy_at(radius=d)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    def describe(disk, name):
        print("%s:" % name)
        print("  Width: %.3f" % disk.width)
        print(" Height: %.3f" % disk.height)
        print(" Radius: %.3f" % disk.radius)
        for r in disk.rects:
            print("   Rect: (%.3f, %.3f) - (%.3f, %.3f), distance %.3f" % (*r.aabb, r.distance))

    disk = Disk( Rect(2.0, 1.0,  4.0,  15),
                 Rect(4.0, 2.0,  4.0,  85),
                 Rect(1.0, 1.0,  4.0, 140),
                 Rect(2.0, 3.0,  4.0, 300) )
    describe(disk, "Initial disk")

    other = disk.resized_to(8.0, 6.0)
    describe(other, "If bounding box set to 8.0 by 6.0")

    other = disk.resized_to(30.0, 24.0)
    describe(other, "If bounding box set to 30.0 by 24.0")
```

If run, it constructs a disk of radius $4$ with four rectangles around it.  It then uses the `resized_to()` method of the `Disk` class to resize the disk so that the resulting bounding box matches the specified width and/or height.

The `size_at_radius()` method computes the bounding box size, if the disk was resized to the specified radius and all rectangles moved correspondingly.  The `copy_at()` method returns the same as a new Disk object, without modifying the original.

Both functions use the `Rect.distance` setter method to compute the new location of each rectangle, with the calculations in `Rect._set_x_y_d` in the first file; which in turn is a straightforward implementation of $\eqref{G1d}$.

The `resized_to()` method uses the `size_at_radius()` method to bracket the radius range, then a binary search to find the radius that yields the best bounding box size.

I have not proven that the disk bounding box size is a smooth enough function for a binary search to be reasonable (converge to either the global extremum, or to a local one so near to the global one that the difference is within rounding error), but the behaviour of $\eqref{G1a}$ makes me believe so.

The code is not production quality; it probably contains typos and other bugs (none intentionally!), so anyone intending to use this should really test their code well with different datasets before relying on it.  However, it should clearly show how $\eqref{G1a}$ is inverted (and running `rect.py` verifies this with lots of random rectangles), and how a binary search can be used to find a disk radius that yields a desired bounding box size.

It may not behave sensibly when the origin (center of disk) is within a rectangle, though.

At minimum, consider limiting the binary search to meaningful differences in disk radiuses.  As it is, the binary search only ends if a desired bounding box size is found, or when the limit of precision is reached.

The bracketing part extends the minimum and maximum radius, until it covers the desired bounding box size.  Note that when the maximum has to be extended, we could set the minimum radius to the old maximum radius, so that we *move* the range rather than scale it; and vice versa for when extending the minimum.  So, there are definitely lots of optimization opportunities.

It is just example code, after all.