# Position a rectangle inside a circle along the circumference

Tags: trigonometry, circles

Suppose I'd like to position a rectangle inside a circle such that:

1. The center point of the rectangle (*p*, *q*) lies along the radius defined by *θ*
2. The rectangle is positioned at the maximum radius from the circle center (without exiting the circle)

How can I determine the position (*p*, *q*) of the center of this rectangle (relative to the center of the circle (*x*, *y*))?

I have these parameters available:

- *r*: radius of the circle
- *θ*: angle of this radius along which (p,q) lies
- *w,h*: width and height of the rectangle
- *x,y*: location of the center of the circle

[This question is related to the one asked by Mahozad](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4152307/shift-a-rectangle-located-on-circle-circumference-so-they-do-not-overlap), except they asked about the rectangle along the outside of the circle.  In this question, I'm interested in the rectangle remaining inside the circle.

Images show $\theta \in (\pi/2, \pi)$ and $\theta=\pi,$ respectively.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Follow these guidelines to get help in this forum. It's particularly important that you share your own work and thoughts on the problem to show that you have made a serious effort by yourself before asking for help, and you're not just trying to get others to solve it for you.

Comment: @Mike Yan: Wlog can we take $(x,y)=(0,0)?$..and  is $ \tan \theta =q/p$ given?

Comment: Hi @Narasimham, (x,y) cannot be taken to be (0,0) in the actual problem I'm trying to solve (related to computer graphics), but I don't see why it would be an issue to just translate the result later.

I'm not sure how to answer the second part of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p^2 + q^2 = d^2$ where $d = f(\theta)$ represents distance of center of rectangle from center of circle as function of $\theta$.

Then $(p,q) = (x + d\cos\theta, y + d\sin\theta)$

Applying cosine law on triangle connecting center of circle, center of rectangle and vertex of rectangle touching the circle,
$ d^2 + d (w \cos\theta + h \sin \theta) + {(\frac{w}{2})^2} + {(\frac{h}{2})^2} - r^2 = 0$

Solving quadratic equation for positive $d$, we get
$d = \frac{\sqrt{(w \cos\theta + h \sin \theta)^2 + 4r^2 - w^2 - h^2}-(w \cos\theta + h \sin \theta)}{2}$

The above formula is valid for $\theta \in (0, \frac{\pi}{2})$.
By symmetry, formula for other cases can be derived.

Let $m = \lfloor\frac{2\theta}{\pi} \rfloor$ and $\alpha = (-1)^m (\theta - \lfloor\frac{m+1}{2} \rfloor \pi)$

Then,for all angles, $d = \frac{\sqrt{(w \cos\alpha + h \sin \alpha)^2 + 4r^2 - w^2 - h^2}-(w \cos\alpha + h \sin \alpha)}{2}$

I wrote following code (with center of circle at (0,0)) demonstrating this formula in action.

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

def c(r,w,h,theta):
    f = 2*theta // np.pi 
    th = (-1)**f * (theta - (f+1)//2 * np.pi)
    b = w*np.cos(th) + h*np.sin(th)
    d = ((b*b + 4*r*r - w*w - h*h)**0.5 - b)/2
    return (d*np.cos(theta), d*np.sin(theta))

theta = np.linspace(-np.pi,np.pi,100)
r = 10
w = 3 
h = 4 
center = np.array([c(r,w,h,t) for t in theta])
circle = np.array([[r*np.cos(t), r*np.sin(t)] for t in theta])

for cc in center:
    plt.gca().add_patch(Rectangle((cc[0]-w/2, cc[1]-h/2), w, h, fill=False))

plt.plot(center[:,0],center[:,1],'r')
plt.plot(circle[:,0], circle[:,1],'g')
plt.axis('square')
plt.show()
```

Red curve is the locus of center of rectangle.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @gsomani, for the very thoughtful answer. This seems to solve the problem when (x,y) = (0,0).  Pardon the pedantry, but we may want to update the answer to include the translation by (x,y) to make the solution more fully match the question.

Comment: That just translates center of rectangle also by (x,y). Updated the answer to include (x,y).

Comment: If it is helpful, can you accept it ?

Comment: Thanks! I just did. I'm new to the community, so I didn't realize I could accept the answer.  (It wouldn't even let me upvote because I'm new). The community rules seem so strict, I was concerned that even saying thanks would be against platform rules. Hope this reply is ok.  I appreciate your thoughtful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\theta \in (0, \frac{\pi}{2})$, then clearly the upper right corner of the rectangle must be on the boundary of the circle (for the other quadrants it will be a different corner point of the rectangle).

Let the centre of the rectangle be located at a distance of $s$ from the centre of circle. We want to find $s$ as $p = s \cos \theta$ and $q = s \sin \theta$
. Then we must have $ (s \cos \theta + \frac{w}{2})^2 + (s \sin \theta + \frac{h}{2})^2 = r^2 \Rightarrow s^2 + (w \cos \theta + h \sin \theta) s + \frac{w^2 + h^2 - 4r^2}{4} = 0$.

P.S: I just realized that @gsomani has the exact same method as mine.