# Find the position of a rectangle that touches a given circle when the direction of the line joining their centres are known.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles, rectangles

I have a rectangle, the sides of which are parallel to $x\text{-}$ and $y\text{-axis}$. The length of the sides are known, i.e., width = $W$ and height = $H$. I also have a circle of radius $R$ with its centre at $\left(x, y\right)$.

Now, as shown in the sketches given below, I need to position the rectangle so that it touches the circle while the line joining their individual centres making a known angle of $\alpha$ with the positive $y\text{-axis}$.

I am unable to find a simple solution. If someone has an idea how to solve this problem, please share it with me. For programming, I am using the language Python.

[image: First example]

[image: Second example]

Comment: Just found this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4152446/1153753

Comment: Actually this link is not exactly the same case, because in my case, W²+H²>(2R)²

Comment: One of the answers to [the other question you found](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4152307/139123) has some inaccuracies when the desired angle between the centers is close to $0$ or to $90$ degrees, but these inaccuracies are easily corrected. (I have posted an answer with the corrections.) There is another answer that I have not fully understood, but it also produces accurate results and it appears to have no limitations on the size of the rectangle. My answer also has no limitations on the size of the rectangle.